# To get PYTHONPATH correct in running Django

Tags: django, macos, pythonpath

I run at [a cloned Django](http://github.com/cnprog/CNPROG/tree/master) repository

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

The problem is in my PYTHONPATH according to MacPorts' IRC.

I run

```
ls -l $(which python)
```

I get

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    68B Jan 29 12:27 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python
```

This command suggests according to krunk that my PATHs are incorrect: /opt/local/... should be before /usr/local/...

However, I am not sure what he means.

My PYTHONPATH in ~/.zshrc is

```
export PYTHONPATH=/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/:$HOME/.python_libraries:
```

where /opt/local/... is the first PATH as krunk suggests.

I run

```
which $PYTHONPATH
/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/:/Users/Sam/.python_libraries: not found
```

My PYTHONPATH has something wrong: apparently the /opt/locall/... is not right.

**How can you get the PYTHONPATH correct?**

Comment: Silly question: Have you installed Django?

Comment: @Greg: I did that by MacPorts. I know that it should fix the PYTHONPATH. However, it did not happen for some reason for me.

Comment: I don't know about Django specifically, but I wouldn't expect that installing a Python module would modify the PYTHONPATH environment variable at all. And even if it did, how would it know to edit it in your local `.zshrc` file? If you need to point the PYTHONPATH somewhere specific for Django, you'll probably have to do that manually according to the installation instructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not with PYTHONPATH, it's with PATH itself -- `echo $PATH` to see it, `export PATH=whatever` to change it (you can do that in your ~/.bashrc for example).

You'll see that in your current PATH /usr/local/bin comes before /opt/local/bin -- you need to swap them if you want `python` to be running from your MacPorts.  Alternatively, of course, you can choose to explicitly run /opt/local/bin/python ...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using macports, and install Python using Jesse Noller's instructions at http://jessenoller.com/2009/03/16/so-you-want-to-use-python-on-the-mac/

His instructions assume Bash, but should work the same for zsh.